# Computing the order of the product of two entire functions

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Let $f_1$ and $f_2$ be entire functions of growth order $a$ and $b$ such that $a$ and $b$ are *different*. I managed to show that the growth order of the product of the two functions is less or equal than the maximum of $a$ and $b$. However now I am required to prove that the growth order is 'equal' to the the maximum of $a$ and $b$. I can't find a way to show the equality...Could anyone help me?

Comment: I *think* the rough idea is to assume $\rho(f_1) < \rho(f_2)$ and  $\rho(f_1 f_2) < \rho(f_2)$ and then derive a contradiction from $f_2 = (f_1 f_2)/f_1$, and for that you need a lower bound of $f_1$ which – if I remember correctly – can be achieved using the Weierstraß product representation.

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail?

Comment: I tried the hadamard factorization theorem too but failed to apply it properly...

Answer (score 1):

This requires an estimate of the entire function of smaller order from below, which is not trivial. Look in B. Levin,  Distribution of zeros of entire functions. American Mathematical Society, Providence, R.I., 1980,
Chap. I, $\S$ 9, Theorem 12 a).